# Excel: Is it possible to add X cells for a specific date and when the date changes (on its own column) then add the next Y cells below that new date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have an excel sheet with a simple sum fuction, but I want that fuction to work for all the products on a specific date. E.x Lets say that on 14/12/2021 I received 20 products each one with different size. I want the add fuction to add all the sizes together on that date and create a number but when the new shipment comes on e.x 25/01/2022 I need the add fuction to add the products after that date and ignore the products and their sizes before that date. Is something like that possible ? Thank you in advance for the enlightening

Sample: [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtE9e.png)
I need basicaly in every different date the sizes of the products (how many small medium large items etc) that are next to that date to be added and get a result for each shipment

Comment: Doesn't make sense.

Comment: please add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand right... Every row has several columns that should be summed. Sometimes several rows have the same date then all rows and columns with the same date should be summed.

```
=SUM(C2:D2)
=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,A2)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes every date has different shipments of clothes lets say with different sizes. I need to add all the clothes that arrived a specific date and all of their sizes and display a sum. On the next shipment on a next day i need a fuction to create a different sum for the other new products with their sizes. I guess only with 2 fuctions not only one fuction trick?

Answer (score -1):

I assume this is what you want:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A5,MAX(A2:A5),C2:C5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am trying to implement this solution, I added an example image as link. I need basicaly in every different date the sizes of the products (how many small medium large items etc)  that are next to that date to be added and get a result for each shipment